# How do I extract string from pattern to pattern?

Tags: c++, string, file, binary, design-patterns

I am trying to extract a string between two patterns from another string in C++.

> Example of input: "C++ is not that easy"
>
> Pattern1: "C++"
>
> Pattern2: "that"
>
> Result: " is not "

I would like to loop this operation to extract all matching strings from binary file later.

Comment: Actually I found a small app which do exactly what I wanted but thanks anyway, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way for this is to use regular expressions.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4384yce9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That's fine if you're using .NET. For standard C++, there's either Boost.Regex, or the C++0x regex library.

Comment: There's a link in the page for non .net solutions.
But thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string::find()` to find the position of each pattern within the input, `string::length()` to find the end position of the first pattern (since `find()` gives the start),and then `string::substr()` to extract the substring between those positions.